# How to display iPhone dev log on phone?

Tags: iphone

How can I see the developer's debug log of a running app? Is there an app for this? I have a windows machine, is there some way that I can see this through an app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the free (or $.99)app named "Console" to see it on the phone.